# UWP change style of selected ListViewItem

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a ListView. It is not dynamic, I am giving it's `ListViewItem` in the XAML like this. There are very few `ListViewItem`s in the `ListView`. The XAML is like this:

```
<ListView Name="ABC">
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel>
            <BitmapIcon/>
            <TextBlock/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>

     <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel>
            <BitmapIcon/>
            <TextBlock/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>

     <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel>
            <BitmapIcon/>
            <TextBlock/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

When a `ListViewItem` gets selected, I want to change the `Foreground` property of the `BitmapIcon` inside the `ListViewItem` to some other value. How do I achieve this. I am open to changing the `ListView`  to some lighter controls like `ItemsControl` as long as I am able to change the Foreground property of the `BitmapIcon`.

Comment: Do you dynamically create the list?

Comment: NO, it's static, all ListViewItems defined in XAML itself. There are only 4 `ListViewItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done inside the *Style* of the `ListViewItem`. You just need to change the `SelectedForeground` to whatever color you like. For example -

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                                       ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                       CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}"
                                       ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                       CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                                       DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                                       DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                       DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}"
                                       DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                       FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"
                                       FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryThickness}"
                                       FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                                       FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                                       FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryThickness}"
                                       FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                                       FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                                       PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                                       PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                                       PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                                       PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                                       ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                       SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                                       SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                                       SelectedForeground="LightBlue"
                                       SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                                       SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"
                                       VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As long as you don't specify the `Foreground` property on your `BitmapIcon`, it will automatically get the updated color (from `SelectedForeground` in the style above) when the `ListViewItem` gets selected.